# Why isn't the GWT Query Param of type Date serializing with the default date format when the timezone is set to UTC-XX?

Tags: gwt, resty-gwt

In GWT Query param of type Date does not get serialized using the default (unix time) date format when  timezone is set to any of (UTC-XX) timezones.

E.g. Query param:

```
Thu+May+19+10%3A47%3A09+GMT-100+2022
default format used : EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy
GWT version:2.7.0 and resty-gwt-2.2.0
Api: https://localhost:8080/orders?OrderDate=Thu+May+19+10%3A47%3A09+GMT-100+2022
```

Comment: Hi @Nithya, could you update the question to show us what you think the query param should like when it is formatted and updated correctly?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMerchant, the problem is when set to UTC - XX timezone i get serialization exception and the api returns 400 bad request..There is no problem with the default format as it works for UTC+ timezones

Comment: Thanks all for the reply..With latest upgrade to resty-gwt 2.2.7 version the issue resolved.